Was Riemann's research style closer to the 'collaborative' style of Grothendieck and von Neumann?
Or was he more of an 'independent' style like his teacher Gauss?
If you can give an objectively correct answer to this, what is the basis for it?

the Riemann-Roch theorem was not from those two working together.  Riemann proved something, then years later Roch improved it.

Riemann had no joint publications, except the book which H. Weber wrote after his death, and which was based on Riemann's lectures.
